# C# - MVC - How to list multiple entries based on one foreign key

Tags: c#, database, list, foreign-keys

This is my first post so I apologize for my lack of awareness.

I am trying to select a number of items linked to a category, based on the selected categories ID. I know I need to somehow utilize the created list in the model, but I am not sure how.

In other words, I want to list Menu Items on the Category "Details" view, based on which category is selected on the site.

**MenuCategory Model**

```
public class MenuCategory
{
    public int MenuCategoryId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }     
    public List<MenuItem> MenuItems
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

**MenuItem Model**

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public int MenuItemId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Image
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [ForeignKey("MenuCategory")]
    public int MenuCategoryId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public MenuCategory MenuCategory
    {
        get;
        set;
    }        
}
```

**MenuCategory View Index**

```
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>

                <a asp-controller="MenuCategories" asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.MenuCategoryId">
                Details
                </a> 

            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
```

**MenuCategory Details View**

```
  @model Farbucks.Models.MenuCategory

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>MenuCategory</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </dt>

    </dl>
</div>

@foreach (var item in Model.MenuItems)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
}
```

**MenuCategories Controller**

```
{
    public class MenuCategoriesController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public MenuCategoriesController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: MenuCategories
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.MenuCategory.ToListAsync());
        }

        // GET: MenuCategories/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var menuCategory = await _context.MenuCategory
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.MenuCategoryId == id);
            if (menuCategory == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(menuCategory);
        }


    }
}
```

**MenuItems Controller**

```
{
    public class MenuItemsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public MenuItemsController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: MenuItems
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var applicationDbContext = _context.MenuItem.Include(m => m.MenuCategory);
            return View(await applicationDbContext.ToListAsync());
        }

        // GET: MenuItems/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var menuItem = await _context.MenuItem
                .Include(m => m.MenuCategory)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.MenuItemId == id);
            if (menuItem == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(menuItem);
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **MenuCategory Details View**, You can get list of MenuItems by using [Lazy loading in entity](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/lazyloading-in-entity-framework.aspx)

So it looks like the snipped below:

**MenuCategory Details View**

```
foreach(var item in Model.MenuItems)
{
 // display information of Menu item here.
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm now getting an error that the object reference is not set ot an instance of an object. I appreciate what you gave me though.

Comment: You code in action Details, I mean you can get value of  MenuItems at here.
So pls give me your code.

Comment: I just made the update. I'm just a bit lost, sorry about that.

Comment: Nope, action in the controller.

Comment: var menuCategory = await _context.MenuCategory.Where(m => m.MenuCategoryId == id).Select(p => new MenuCategory {  MenuItems = _context.MenuItem.Where(p => p.MenuCategoryId == id).ToList(), // the rest of props  }) ).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

Comment: Would you be able to explain this to me so that I can better understand?

Comment: Simple becuz you .FirstOrDefaultAsync(), It means that you queried to db and disconnect. So that's the reason why you are getting error "he object reference is not set ot an instance of an object". Pls get value on server side (Details action) that i've just updated.

Comment: I think that makes sense. Do you need anything else from me?